# make all moss pages available without password

Tags: sharepoint

hello
evey time a person is enter to a my moss site moss ask him for username and password
i need moss to be available to every one how want to enter like regular site 
without username and password

i am working on sharepoint 2007
Version: 12.0.0.6421

Comment: specify sharepoint version please.

Comment: i am working on sharepoint 2007 Version: 12.0.0.6421

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below steps. More information on this [link](http://old.markharrison.co.uk/blog/2006/06/moss-2007-enable-anonymous_12.htm)

1. Enable anonymous access for a web application from the Central Admin.

   Central Admin Home Page > Application Management > Authentication Providers > select the Membership Provider (authentication.aspx) and enable anonymous access from the next page.

   You don't have to do anything on the IIS Manager ... enabling it from the Central Admin page will also enable it on IIS.
2. Explicitly turn it on for the sites you want to be accessed anonymously.

   Browse to the site, click Site Settings > Advanced Permissions > Settings >Anonymous Access (setanon.aspx) and turn on anonymous access for the site.